# How to add dialog on WTL project

Tags: c++, wtl

I am a newbie on C++ WTL. I want to add a new dialog on my project. I am not sure if WTL has a wizard or something. Please guide me on creating a new dialog box.

Seems my question is not clear.

I need assistance on how to add a dialog box on a WTL project. As I said, I a newbie. I'm not a C++ guy who knows how to use this WTL. I dont have a code, since what I need is a walkthrough and not a source code answer.

Any comment is appreciated, or tutorial site would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on creating dialog boxes using WTL https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3841/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-I-ATL-GUI-Classes#dialogs

Comment: Thanks for this, I finally figured that this needs to be created manually, there is no one click solution for this but to add everything manually. thanks for the tutorial.

Comment: BTW I'm a C# guy and almost zero experience in C++ and from today onward I will expand this cpp knowledge that I have learned

Comment: I learnt C, C++, templates, then WTL in that order. I started out in MFC but WTL is much better in terms of resource usage and more flexibility. I've never coded a windows GUI purely in the API, but that level of understanding would be useful. I've not written a great deal of c# code but things might not work out of the box in WTL that might in C#, be prepared to build stuff yourself / nick it from someone elses code. I found most of what you might rely on in c# is in C++ std library esp. latest versions e.g. c++11 & WTL